# How to initialize nested data class in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, class, inner-classes, data-class

I have the following structure in a data class:

```
data class A(
    val b: Int,
    val c: C
) {
    data class B(
        val d: Int
    )

    data class C(
        val d: Int
    )  
}
```

and an instance of this class is being passed to a method which has the following signarure:

```
fun doSomethingMethod(object: A.B?): Mono<Unit> =
            // do something
            }
```

So now I am trying to initialize an instance of the data class A with only initializing B as wel but I dont understand how to do it. So far I have tried:

```
val testObject = A(A.B(5))
```

But its not working. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what happens?  Is there a compile error, or a runtime error?

Comment: I get a compile error @gidds

Comment: Please post the error.  (Not only will it help us answer your questions, but future visitors may be searching on it.)

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `object` as it is a keyword in kotlin for marking a singleton or creating an anonymous object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an object of nested data class just use next syntax:

```
val instance = OuterClass.NestedClass([params])
```

In your case it will be:

```
val b = A.B(5)
```

Complete example:

```
fun doSomethingMethod(b: A.B?): Mono<Unit> {
    // do something
}

val b = A.B(5)
val mono = doSomethingMethod(b)
```